# rRdfined a built-in function

Tags: python, spyder

Redefined builtin function len() in spyder  like len = 100;
Now when I am trying to find the length of the string it says "'int' object is not callable"
How to undo this change or correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Since len is an inbuilt python function, you should avoid using that as a variable. try prefixing your 'len' with '_' and use '_len = 10' instead of just 'len'.

Comment: But I just did and assigned it a value , len = 100  and when I am trying to find the length of the string it says  'int' object is not callable"